# BUILD FAILED while Installing the Droidsafe Eclipse Plugin->Could not find resource file "/home/user/droidsafe-src/android-lib/droidcalls.jar" to copy

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, blockchain, ubuntu-20.04

I have been trying to install Droidsafe in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I have been following this tutorial: https://github.com/MIT-PAC/droidsafe-src/wiki/Requirements . According to this tutorial I needed to download Java, Eclipse, SDK plugins, etc. Everything worked out fine, (In the 2nd step, to set the root of eclipse installation, I have set it to:

`target.eclipse.platform=/home/risvy_rim/Downloads/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321/eclipse`

hope it was okay.
)

until I reached step 3 of this page:
https://github.com/MIT-PAC/droidsafe-src/wiki/Installing-the-Droidsafe-Eclipse-Plugin

after entering `ant plugin-deploy` command, the following error shows up:

```
risvy_rim@rim:~/droidsafe-src$ cd $DROIDSAFE_SRC_HOME
risvy_rim@rim:~/droidsafe-src$ ant plugin-deploy
Buildfile: /home/risvy_rim/droidsafe-src/build.xml

check-for-changes:

antlr-runs:

build-libs:

droidsafe-calls-build:

droidsafe-calls-build-linux:
     [exec] cd src && javac -target 1.6 -source 1.6 edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/*.java
     [exec] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:3: error: package android.widget does not exist
     [exec] import android.widget.TextView;
     [exec]                      ^
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:4: error: package android.widget does not exist
     [exec] import android.widget.Button;
     [exec]                      ^
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:5: error: package android.widget does not exist
     [exec] import android.widget.Chronometer;
     [exec]                      ^
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:6: error: package android.widget does not exist
     [exec] import android.widget.DigitalClock;
     [exec]                      ^
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:7: error: package android.app does not exist
     [exec] import android.app.Activity;
     [exec]                   ^
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:8: error: package android.app does not exist
     [exec] import android.app.AlarmManager;
     [exec]                   ^
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:9: error: package android.app does not exist
     [exec] import android.app.PendingIntent;
     [exec]                   ^
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:10: error: package android.content does not exist
     [exec] import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
     [exec]                       ^
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:11: error: package android.content does not exist
     [exec] import android.content.Context;
     [exec]                       ^
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:12: error: package android.content does not exist
     [exec] import android.content.Intent;
     [exec]                       ^
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:13: error: package android.database does not exist
     [exec] import android.database.Cursor;
     [exec]                        ^
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:14: error: package android.net does not exist
     [exec] import android.net.Uri;
     [exec]                   ^
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:15: error: package android.widget does not exist
     [exec] import android.widget.RemoteViews;
     [exec]                      ^
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
     [exec]   private static boolean bad_tv (TextView tv) {
     [exec]                                  ^
     [exec]   symbol:   class TextView
     [exec]   location: class DroidSafeCalls
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
     [exec]   public static void setText(TextView tv, int resid) {
     [exec]                              ^
     [exec]   symbol:   class TextView
     [exec]   location: class DroidSafeCalls
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
     [exec]   public static void setText(TextView tv, char[] text, int start, int len) {
     [exec]                              ^
     [exec]   symbol:   class TextView
     [exec]   location: class DroidSafeCalls
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:50: error: cannot find symbol
     [exec]   public static void setText(TextView tv, int resid, TextView.BufferType type) {
     [exec]                              ^
     [exec]   symbol:   class TextView
     [exec]   location: class DroidSafeCalls
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:50: error: package TextView does not exist
     [exec]   public static void setText(TextView tv, int resid, TextView.BufferType type) {
     [exec]                                                              ^
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
     [exec]   public static void setText(TextView tv, CharSequence text) {
     [exec]                              ^
     [exec]   symbol:   class TextView
     [exec]   location: class DroidSafeCalls
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:64: error: cannot find symbol
     [exec]   public static void setText(TextView tv, CharSequence text, 
     [exec]                              ^
     [exec]   symbol:   class TextView
     [exec]   location: class DroidSafeCalls
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:65: error: package TextView does not exist
     [exec]                       TextView.BufferType type) {
     [exec]                               ^
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:77: error: cannot find symbol
     [exec]   public static void setupAlarmService (Context context, 
     [exec]                                         ^
     [exec]   symbol:   class Context
     [exec]   location: class DroidSafeCalls
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:99: error: cannot find symbol
     [exec]   public static Cursor queryURI (Context context, String uri_str, 
     [exec]                                  ^
     [exec]   symbol:   class Context
     [exec]   location: class DroidSafeCalls
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:99: error: cannot find symbol
     [exec]   public static Cursor queryURI (Context context, String uri_str, 
     [exec]                 ^
     [exec]   symbol:   class Cursor
     [exec]   location: class DroidSafeCalls
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:108: error: cannot find symbol
     [exec]   public static Cursor managedQuery (Activity activity, String uri_str, 
     [exec]                                      ^
     [exec]   symbol:   class Activity
     [exec]   location: class DroidSafeCalls
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:108: error: cannot find symbol
     [exec]   public static Cursor managedQuery (Activity activity, String uri_str, 
     [exec]                 ^
     [exec]   symbol:   class Cursor
     [exec]   location: class DroidSafeCalls
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:120: error: cannot find symbol
     [exec]   public static void setOnClickRunActivity (Context context, RemoteViews view,
     [exec]                                             ^
     [exec]   symbol:   class Context
     [exec]   location: class DroidSafeCalls
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:120: error: cannot find symbol
     [exec]   public static void setOnClickRunActivity (Context context, RemoteViews view,
     [exec]                                                              ^
     [exec]   symbol:   class RemoteViews
     [exec]   location: class DroidSafeCalls
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:131: error: cannot find symbol
     [exec]   public static void startActivity (Context context, Class activityClass) {
     [exec]                                     ^
     [exec]   symbol:   class Context
     [exec]   location: class DroidSafeCalls
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
     [exec]     return (tv instanceof Button) || (tv instanceof Chronometer)
     [exec]                           ^
     [exec]   symbol:   class Button
     [exec]   location: class DroidSafeCalls
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
     [exec]     return (tv instanceof Button) || (tv instanceof Chronometer)
     [exec]                                                     ^
     [exec]   symbol:   class Chronometer
     [exec]   location: class DroidSafeCalls
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
     [exec]       || (tv instanceof DigitalClock);
     [exec]                         ^
     [exec]   symbol:   class DigitalClock
     [exec]   location: class DroidSafeCalls
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:81: error: cannot find symbol
     [exec]     Intent intent = new Intent(context, service_class);  
     [exec]     ^
     [exec]   symbol:   class Intent
     [exec]   location: class DroidSafeCalls
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:81: error: cannot find symbol
     [exec]     Intent intent = new Intent(context, service_class);  
     [exec]                         ^
     [exec]   symbol:   class Intent
     [exec]   location: class DroidSafeCalls
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:82: error: cannot find symbol
     [exec]     PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, -1, intent,
     [exec]     ^
     [exec]   symbol:   class PendingIntent
     [exec]   location: class DroidSafeCalls
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:83: error: cannot find symbol
     [exec]         PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); 
     [exec]         ^
     [exec]   symbol:   variable PendingIntent
     [exec]   location: class DroidSafeCalls
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:82: error: cannot find symbol
     [exec]     PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, -1, intent,
     [exec]                                   ^
     [exec]   symbol:   variable PendingIntent
     [exec]   location: class DroidSafeCalls
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:86: error: cannot find symbol
     [exec]     AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
     [exec]     ^
     [exec]   symbol:   class AlarmManager
     [exec]   location: class DroidSafeCalls
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:86: error: cannot find symbol
     [exec]     AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
     [exec]                                  ^
     [exec]   symbol:   class AlarmManager
     [exec]   location: class DroidSafeCalls
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:87: error: cannot find symbol
     [exec]         .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE); // <5>
     [exec]                           ^
     [exec]   symbol:   variable Context
     [exec]   location: class DroidSafeCalls
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:88: error: cannot find symbol
     [exec]     alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, System
     [exec]                                      ^
     [exec]   symbol:   variable AlarmManager
     [exec]   location: class DroidSafeCalls
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:104: error: cannot find symbol
     [exec]       .query (Uri.parse (uri_str), projection, selection, selectionArgs,
     [exec]               ^
     [exec]   symbol:   variable Uri
     [exec]   location: class DroidSafeCalls
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:112: error: cannot find symbol
     [exec]     return activity.managedQuery (Uri.parse (uri_str), projection, selection,
     [exec]                                   ^
     [exec]   symbol:   variable Uri
     [exec]   location: class DroidSafeCalls
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:124: error: cannot find symbol
     [exec]               .getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context,
     [exec]                                            ^
     [exec]   symbol:   class Intent
     [exec]   location: class DroidSafeCalls
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:123: error: cannot find symbol
     [exec]     view.setOnClickPendingIntent(viewId, PendingIntent
     [exec]                                          ^
     [exec]   symbol:   variable PendingIntent
     [exec]   location: class DroidSafeCalls
     [exec] edu/mit/csail/droidsafe/DroidSafeCalls.java:132: error: cannot find symbol
     [exec]     context.startActivity (new Intent (context, activityClass));
     [exec]                                ^
     [exec]   symbol:   class Intent
     [exec]   location: class DroidSafeCalls
     [exec] 46 errors
     [exec] 1 warning
     [exec] make: *** [Makefile:7: build] Error 1
     [exec] Result: 2

droidsafe-calls-build-windows:

compile-model:

compile-manual-model:
   [delete] Deleting: /home/risvy_rim/droidsafe-src/android-lib/droidsafe-manual-api-model.jar
      [jar] Building jar: /home/risvy_rim/droidsafe-src/android-lib/droidsafe-manual-api-model.jar

compile-ds:

compile:

plugin:

BUILD FAILED
/home/risvy_rim/droidsafe-src/build.xml:506: Warning: Could not find resource file "/home/risvy_rim/droidsafe-src/android-lib/droidcalls.jar" to copy.

Total time: 0 seconds
```

Comment: Well Eclipse hasn't been supported for Android development for a long time now, and that project doesn't appear to have been updated in at least 6 years, so it may be that it is all too old to work anymore.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But can I use Android studio instead of eclipse+sdk? Again, we were trying to install Droidsafe in the first place.